react how to reset state after using effect
I have a page with a Button A. When clicked, it makes an API call, and if successful, opens a new page. While the API call is being made, a modal appears to inform the user that a request is ongoing.
The modal contains a cancel button. If clicked, the new page should not open, and the state should reset so the user can cancel again if needed.
I use the useEffect hook to detect if the cancel button is clicked. If it is, the new page will not open. For the api call, I used await instead of settimeout(..)
I need to reset the variables in useEffect after the new page is either opened or not. I haven't found a solution that handles the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. It's essential to ensure that every time the cancel button is clicked, the user can click Button A and cancel the action repeatedly.
import React, {  useState, useRef, useEffect  } from 'react';

export default function NewApp(props) {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [apiRequestSuccessful, setApiRequestSuccessful] = useState(false);
  const [isCancelClicked, setIsCancelClicked] = useState(false);


  const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    // Open the modal
    setIsModalOpen(true);
    setIsCancelClicked(false);

    try {
      // Make the API request
      setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("making api call")
      },3000)
        setApiRequestSuccessful(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('API request failed', error);
    }
  };

  const handleCancelClick = () => {
    setIsCancelClicked(true);
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if the API request was successful and the cancel button wasn't clicked
    if (apiRequestSuccessful && !isCancelClicked) {
     window.open('https://example.com', '_blank');
    // console.log("open new window")
    }
    setIsModalOpen(false)
  }, [apiRequestSuccessful, isCancelClicked]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Button A</button>
      {isModalOpen && (
        <Modal onCancel={handleCancelClick} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const Modal = ({ onCancel }) => {
  return (
    <div className="modal">
      <p>Api call is being made...</p>
      <button onClick={onCancel}>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  );
};


You don't need the effect. That is an unnecessary performance overhead. Close the modal and open the new tab when the request completes successfully.

the problem is when the request is successeful but the user clicks on cancel, the new window should not open in this case

Use an AbortController:
const reqCtrl = new AbortController()
You can cancel a fetch() invocation using this AbortController and you will not open() the new tab:
const handleButtonClick = () => {
  /* •••Rest of code••• */
  fetch(url, { signal: reqCtrl.signal })
  .then(res => {
    /* •••Rest of code••• */
    setIsModalOpen(false)
    window.open(•••)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Request Error: ", err)
  })
}
Invoking abort() on the AbortController should be the responsibility of the cancel function:
const handleCancelClick = () => {
  reqCtrl.abort()
  setIsModalOpen(false)
}

This example uses fetch() because you mentioned that this is your actual use case. If it were to address the OP code, it would be a different implementation.

this didn't work with useQuery, it there a way to check if the query was aborted so I can set my data to null?

useQuery? What's that? Is that a react hook provided by an external library? Can you share a link and a [mre]?

yes it's this library https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/reference/useQuery

There is Default Query Function. Define one since you are using AbortController.

I did, and I called cancelQueries, there is no result returned which is OK but why do I still see the request with return status 200 on the browser inspect>network tab. is that normal?

Cancelling promises is difficult, you can store the request state in a state variable but you also have to store the request number or ID so that only the last request will count to go to the next page.
const [requestNum, setRequestNum] = useState(0);
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

handleCancelClick = () => {
  this.setRequestNum(this.requestNum + 1)
  this.setShowModal(false)
}

handleShowModalClick = () => {
  const reqNum = this.requestNum
  this.setShowModal(true)
  try {
    // Make the API request
    setTimeout(() => {
       // API request success opens new page
       if (reqNum === this.requestNum) {
         window.open('https://example.com', '_blank');
       }
    },3000)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('API request failed', error);
  }
}

In this simplified example, the page only changes if the request is the latest request made, you can apply the same logic and if the request fails and is the latest request show an error message on the modal (if its open) etc.

but if the request succeeds and the user clicks on cancel, the window still openes

no, if the user clicks cancel, the request number is incremented and the request is ignored when it arrives

due to  the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, the update of the requestNb is happening after the api finished calling. React doesn't guarantee intant update of the state.

not sure I follow, setState() is synchronous, the requestNb should be incremented when cancel is clicked, when the api finishes calling it checks the current value of requestNb against the value when it was called

maybe you're adapting the solution to a problem I don´t fully understand, the example I gave should work though its basic

it is exactly the same code I shared except I make a real api call. I used your code but I found that the compare always gives true. So I did console.log and found that the setRequestNum(..) is happening after the window.open. I searched over the doc of react and found that the state takes time and perhaps that explains the issue.

strange, even if so the update should take very little, not enough to interfere, I still think there may be typo somewhere, but thanks for clarifying and sorry it does not work

Why not store the fetch object in the state and once the cancel button is clicked you can cancel the fetch request? In the effect you can monitor the state of your fetch, if the fetch is canceled it will not open the new page but if it's successful it will close the modal and present the new page. By that, there is no need to disable the cancel button; all states will be connected to your API request status.
But if you insist on using state, can you explain when the state needs to be reseated and what state needs to be rested?
